# How to copy a object data to another object in Django?

Tags: django, object

I am trying to create an E-Commerce Website and I am at the Final Step i.e. Placing the Order. So, I am trying to add all the Cart Items into my Shipment model. But I am getting this error.

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'product'

**Here are my models**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    productId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    productName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    productDescription = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    productRealPrice = models.IntegerField()
    productDiscountedPrice = models.IntegerField()
    productImage = models.ImageField()
    productInformation = RichTextField()
    productTotalQty = models.IntegerField()
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    profileImage = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, default='profile.png')
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)


class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    dateOrdered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    orderCompleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transactionId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)


class Cart(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    dateAdded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Shipment(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    orderId = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    orderDate = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=13)
```

I just removed additional functions i.e. `__str__` and others.

**Here is the views.py**

```
def orderSuccessful(request):
    number = Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user).values('phoneNumber')
    fullAddress = Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user).values('address')
    timeIn = time.time() * 1000  # convert current time in milliSecond
    if request.method == 'POST':
        order = Shipment.objects.create(customer=request.user.customer, orderId=timeIn,
                                        orderDate=datetime.datetime.now(), address=fullAddress,
                                        phoneNumber=number)
        user = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)
        preOrder = Order.objects.filter(customer=user)
        orders = Order.objects.get(customer=request.user.customer, orderCompleted=False)
        items = orders.cart_set.all()  # Here is all the items of cart
        for product in items:
            product = Product.objects.filter(productId=items.product.productId)  # error is on this line
            order.products.add(product)

        Cart.objects.filter(order=preOrder).delete()
        preOrder.delete()
        order.save()
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Problem in Placing the Order")
    context = {
        'shipment': Shipment.objects.get(customer=request.user.customer)
    }
    return render(request, "Amazon/order_success.html", context)
```

How to resolve this error and all the cart items to field products in `Shipment` model?

Comment: `items = orders.cart_set.all()` this is not all the items, it is a queryset of all `Cart` instances related to the `orders` instance

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, then how can I insert a `queryset` into another?

Comment: Is your Order supposed to have only one cart?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yes, It works like this user can have a single order at the current time with multiple products.

Comment: I'll confim can you change this line in the `Cart` model `order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)` to `order = models.OneToOneField(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)`? Or is that different from your intention?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat No, you are right this is what I am trying to do. As I followed some Youtube tutorials they showed their models like this.

Answer (score 2):

Your model is not really consistent at all. Your Cart object is an m:n (or m2m - ManyToMany) relationship between Product and Order. Usually, you would have a 1:n between Cart and Product (a cart contains one or more products). One Cart might be one Order (unless you would allow more than one carts per order). And a shipment is usually a 1:1 for an order. I do not see any of this relationships in your model.

Draw your model down and illustrate the relations between them first - asking yourself, if it should be a 1:1, 1:n or m:n? The latter can be realized with a "through" model which is necessary if you need attributes like quantities.

In this excample, we have one or more customers placing an order filling a cart with several products in different quantities. The order will also need a shipment fee.

By the way: bear in mind that "filter()" returns a list. If you are filtering on user, which is a one to one to a unique User instance, you would better use "get()" as it returns a single instance.
Putting in into a try - except or using get_object_or_404() makes it more stable.

```
product = Product.objects.filter(productId=items.product.productId)
```

should be something like:

```
product = product.product
```

not to say, it becomes obsolete.

Comment: Great answer Friend! Really liked the fact that you explored on modelling.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you make a cart for a product by multiple instances of `Cart`, the problem is you try to access the wrong variable, also you don't need to filter again when you already have the instance, make the following changes:

```
carts = orders.cart_set.all()  # Renamed items to carts for clarity
for cart in carts:
    product = cart.product
    order.products.add(product) # The name order is very misleading makes one think it is an instance of Order, actually it is an instance of Shipment
```

As mentioned above in my comment your variable names are somewhat misleading, please give names that make sense to any variable.